# PDO Insert error (Undefined parameter)

Tags: php, pdo, syntax-error

I am working on a little project and I can't seem to get one of my PDO insert querys to work.
I get the error message:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /home/photobay/public_html/friendcon/register.php:24

And here is my code:

```
$datetime = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(@$_POST['datetime']));
$fname = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(ucfirst(@$_POST['first-name'])));
$lname = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(ucfirst(@$_POST['last-name'])));
$email = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(@$_POST['email']));
$password = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(@$_POST['password']));
$gender = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(@$_POST['gender']));

$password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `first-name`, `last-name`, `email`, `password`, `gender`, `datetime`) VALUES (:id, :first-name, :last-name, :email, :password, :gender, :datetime)");


$stmt->execute(array(
  ':id' => null,
  ':first-name' => $fname,
  ':last-name' => $lname,
  ':email' => $email,
  ':password' => $password,
  ':gender' => $gender,
  ':datetime' => $datetime

));

$insertId = $db->lastInsertId();
```

I have checked and all the parameters are in there, I have 7 fields in my database and there are 7 parameters defined.

I am lost, I can't figure out what's wrong.
**Note: I am a beginner to PDO, and I am using PHP 7 if that helps**

Comment: Can you try renaming your parameters as `firstname` and `lastname` - I'm not sure that you're allowed to use a hyphen in a placeholder name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rename `:first-name`, `:last-name` to `:firstname`, `:lastname` or `:first_name`, `:last_name` and see if it works.